# Auto-it Enable and disable system restore

Tags: windows, windows-7, autoit, system-restore

Is it posible to enable and disable system restore using autoit. I have had a look on Google but i only found how to delete then not disable them. The code must work on windows-8, windows-7 and windows-vista and also windows XP if possible. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, it is possible using the `_SR_CreateRestorePoint` and `_SR_RemoveRestorePoint()` in the systemrestore.au3 UDF. http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/134628-system-restore-udf/

Comment: Those two functions above will create a restore point, these functions: `_SR_Enable` & `_SR_Disable` will turn on and off the system restore.

Comment: @Mr.Hargrove Thanks that helps could you post it as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_SR_Enable` and `_SR_Disable` functions of the [system-restore UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/134628-system-restore-udf/) in autoit will do this for you.